# Angular $http.jsonp error callback with right response

Tags: angularjs, http, jsonp

I am having a issue with Angular $http's jsonp() function. I am trying to get some data from an external URL. This is my code:

```
module.factory('Ajax', function($http) {
  $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  return {
    get: function(url, obj) {
      return $http.post(url, obj);
    },
    getJSON: function(url, obj) {
      return $http.jsonp(url, obj);
    }
  }
});
```

Model:

```
  factory.getQuote = function(symbol) {
      var q = $q.defer();
      Ajax.getJSON(
        "https://my-url.nl/quote/"+symbol+"/all?callback=parseQuote").then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        q.resolve(data);
      }, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log("Error Promise getQuote user.js");
      });
      return q.promise;
  }
  parseQuote = function(test) {
    if (test.status == "OK") {
      console.log(test[$scope.symbolCode])
    }
  }
```

It gets in the callback (parseQuote, and logs the info I need), however, it also logs "Error Promise getQuote user.js", which is in the error/failure callback, which is odd as I do get the data.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution:

```
  factory.getQuote = function(symbol) {
      var q = $q.defer();
      Ajax.getJSON(
        "https://my-url.nl/quote/"+symbol+"/all?callback=JSON_CALLBACK").success(function(data) {
        console.log('SUCCES')
        q.resolve(data);
      }).error(function(data) {
        console.log("Error Promise getQuote user.js");
      });
      return q.promise;
  }
```